# Calling ps -f from Python on different machines, getting different results

Tags: python, macos

I have some tests that require a server. To that end, each time I execute a set of those tests, I start an instance of Tornado or SimpleHTTPServer. However, because several jobs may run at the same time, or the server from the previous run might have hung, I need to check that there are no other processes with the same name as the one "I am in".

So, what I do is: I execute the OS's `ps -f` from python to get the list of the processes currently running on the machine, and I call python's `os.getpid()` to get the id of my process. Then I find the name of my process in the output from `ps -f`.

There are five machines in the testbed, two of them are Linux machines, and three of them are Macs. The thing works great on all of the machines except one Mac. One of the Macs doesn't include the process from which the `ps -f` was called into the output from that `ps`.

The first thing I checked was whether the OS is the same on all the macs, and it is. Could anyone help me understand what the problem is?

Comment: `ps` on Mac works in a different way to Linux.  I suggest you use `psutil` instead which should give consistent results across platforms.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Comment: I found a different way of getting my process's name: simply `" ".join(sys.argv)`. Thanks anyway. What puzzles me is that I get different outputs from ps on one of the three macs in my setup.

Comment: That does not give you the process name, it gives the program name (`sys.arg[0]`).  There can be more than one process running the same program, and a process can dynamically change programs without changing its pid.